# Ruby Dropdown select based on first character

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a dropdown of vehicle makes that I want my users to start selecting as they type. First character typed should find the first character in the makes. The problem is that it searches anywhere in the make for a character and does not start at the first character like my users would like. For example... if you type an "r" you get: Alfa Romeo, Aston Martin, Chevrolet, Chrysler, etc... well before you get a Renault.
I create my list from the database. My haml looks like this:

```
 .field-row
   = render partial:'/makes/make_select', locals:{id:'make_id'}
```

That calls this _make_select.html.haml

```
 = collection_select :vehicle, id, Make.all.order(:name), :id, :name, {prompt:true}, {title:'Select Make', class:'make-select', 'data-allow-empty' => 'no'}
```

I cant seem to find any docs on Ruby that shows me the valid options for collection_select. Maybe there is an option that allows this?
I have read that I might need to use jQuery to accomplish this. Was just trying to figure out if there might be an easier way with just a simple option in the haml.
Let me know if there is anything else you would like to see.
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could add logic to your controller and to check using a SQL query, something like this, depends on the database you're using.

```
@makes = Make.where('name LIKE ?', "#{params[character]}%")
```

Check out the MySql docs on pattern matching
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html

Comment: When I add that into my Makes controller nothing seems to happen. Im new to Ruby so was curious if it should be hitting the controller as I start typing characters?

Comment: No, the params will get sent when you submit the form and then return the results. Does the query work when you submit the form? Once you're getting the correct results,  if you want some autocomplete functionality you're going to need to implement some javascript to get the keypress events as the form is filled in. There are lots of jquery autocomplete gems for rails such as: https://github.com/bigtunacan/rails-jquery-autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

You should not add your Model query inside a view, should add it.

In your above case, I suggest you use https://github.com/argerim/select2-rails it very powerful and already have what you need.